# Spring Data query by nested collection method signature

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-repositories

I have User and Role entities. There is a many to many relation between them. How can I define repository method for finding all users having a specified role? I tried `findByRolesContaining`, `findByRolesContains` but both seems not to work.

Do I need to use native query or is it possible with method declaration?

`User` entity

```
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String username;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "user_role",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
    )
    private Collection<Role> roles;

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    private String password;

    private boolean enabled;

    // getters and setters ...
}
```

`Role` entity

```
@Entity
public class Role {

    public static final String SUPER_ADMIN = "SUPER_ADMIN";

    public static final String PROJECT_MANAGER = "PROJECT_MANAGER";

    public static final String DEVELOPER = "DEVELOPER";

    public static final String CLIENT = "CLIENT";

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
    private Collection<User> users;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "role_privilege",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "privilege_id")
    )
    private Collection<Privilege> privileges;

    public Role() {

    }

    public Role(String name) {

        this.name = name;
    }

    public Long getId() {

        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {

        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {

        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {

        this.name = name;
    }

    public Collection<User> getUsers() {

        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(Collection<User> users) {

        this.users = users;
    }

    public Collection<Privilege> getPrivileges() {

        return privileges;
    }

    public void setPrivileges(Collection<Privilege> privileges) {

        this.privileges = privileges;
    }
}
```

I need a method for my `UserRepository` interface like
`List<User> findByRole(Role role);`
Which will return all users who has role specified in the parameter (which is contained in User.roles collection.

Comment: can you share your code please?

Comment: why not finding the role so you can get the `Collection<User>`, what I mean `Role findByName(String roleName);` then you can use `List<User> users = findByName("roleName").getUsers();`

Answer (score 0):

I believe that simply `findByRoles` should be enough.

I would also recommend using @Query annotation with JPQL anytime you have problems with method names.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query